# Mysql: MyISAM table files deleted, but still inserting and selecting data. HOW?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain me, what is happening here,

I created one table in MyISAM.

`show tables` -- shows it.
`select` command gives `empty table` from the table.

I delete the myisam files from location.

`show tables` -- does not show it.

Ok till now.

Now, still I am able to insert into table, and able to select from the table [can it happen?? how??]

Again, `drop table` says table does not exist.
and after this, `select` command says table does not exist.

Question is "where did it get inserted, and from where it is selecting the data; and after drop table call, where did it vanish?"

Server version: 5.5.38-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

The overall sequence ..

```
MySQL [test]> CREATE TABLE test (id int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

MySQL [test]> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| test           |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> select * from test;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[root@localhost test]# pwd
/var/lib/mysql/test
[root@localhost test]# ll
total 16
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 8556 Dec 23 14:08 test.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    0 Dec 23 14:08 test.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1024 Dec 23 14:08 test.MYI
[root@localhost test]# rm -f *
[root@localhost test]# ll
total 0
[root@localhost test]#
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
MySQL [test]> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> insert into test values (1234);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> select * from test;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1234 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> drop table test;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'test'

MySQL [test]> select * from test;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.test' doesn't exist
```

Comment: The MySQL server keeps some stuff in memory. It only goes to disk when it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, if you remove a file that another process has opened, it just removes the name from the directory, but the file still exists on disk, and the other process can continue to access it. It doesn't really go away until all processes close the file.

The MySQL daemon presumably opens the files related to a table the first time it's accessed, and then keeps the file open for as long as it can. So once it has accessed a table, removing the filename doesn't affect its operations on the contents of the table.

However, DML operations like `show tables` and `drop tables` work by accessing the directory, not the open files, so they notice the change. Then all the internal data structures are sync'ed with the filesystem.